# How to pass data between two UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, delegates, radio-button

I would like to pass data between two UITableViewControllers. In first UITableViewController I display NewPackageViewController which contains some cells like in code below:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section ==0)
    {
        UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 310, 44)];
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Set package number here"];
        [textField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically: YES];

        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
        [aCell addSubview:textField];
    }
        else if(indexPath.section ==1){
            aCell  =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            [aCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            [aCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            aCell.textLabel.text = creationDate;
            aCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Choose";
            aCell.imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Date.png"] ;



    }
    else if(indexPath.section ==2)
    {
          [aCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        aCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        aCell.textLabel.text = self.storeName;


        aCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buildings2020.png"];

    aCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Choose";

    }
    else if(indexPath.section ==4){
        aCell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        aCell.textLabel.text = @"Add package item";
        [aCell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        aCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"New.png"];
        [aCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        aCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else if(indexPath.section ==5){
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 100)];
        [textView setEditable:YES];
        [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:14]];
        [textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

        textView.delegate = self;

         [aCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [aCell addSubview:textView];

    }



return aCell;
```

}

After clicking on the section == 2 my app properly display second UITableView :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switch (indexPath.section)
{
    case ...:
break;
........
   case 2:
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectStoreView"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController
alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES
completion:nil];
break; }
default:
break;
```

In SelectStoreViewController I implemented checkmarks

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return arrayOfStores.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
cell.textLabel.text= [arrayOfStores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buildings2020.png"];
return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
}
```

In SelectStoreViewController I created delegate with method like below:

SelectStoreViewController.h

```
@class SelectStoreViewController;
@protocol PassStoreNameDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)setStoreName:(SelectStoreViewController*)controller
didFinishEnteringStoreName:(NSString*)enteredStoreName;
@end
@interface SelectStoreViewController :
UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *checkedIndexPath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfStores ;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<PassStoreNameDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

SelectStoreViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
arrayOfStores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self fetchStoresFromDatabase];
self.title = @"Select store from list";
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back"
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
action:@selector(didSelectBackBarButtonItem:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
}
-(void)didSelectBackBarButtonItem:(id)sender{
[self.delegate setStoreName:self didFinishEnteringStoreName:@"store name"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After that I implement PassStoreNameDelegate in NewPackageViewController (in my first UITableViewController)
NewPackageViewController.h

```
interface NewPackageViewController :
UITableViewController<UITextViewDelegate,PassStoreNameDelegate,CreationDateViewDelegate>
{
SelectStoreViewController *selectStoreNameViewController;
NSString *storeName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) SelectStoreViewController*selectStoreNameViewController;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString* storeName;
@end
```

NewPackageViewController.m

```
-(void)setStoreName:(SelectStoreViewController *)controllerdidFinishEnteringStoreName
(NSString *)enteredStoreName{
self.storeName = enteredStoreName;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

When trying to perform this task I used this link:[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559)

I would like to create functionality similar to radio button...
Every help will be appriciated

Ragards

Answer (score 0):

First you should create radio button function in .h file. then implement your code in your 1st view controller.

The only thing you want to do is in 2nd view controller .h file import "secondviewController.h"

Then surely you can use that radio button function in secondviewController.m file

Comment: I'don't know how this radio button function should looks like:/ I didn't provide references because it seemed to me that it is obvious that they must be there...

Comment: what is the real name of that radio button. I mean the official name.